# How is experience awarded for critical hits?

Tags: experience-points, rolemaster-rm2

When awarding experience in *Rolemaster Classic* for critical hits is it the crit level rolled or the crit level adjusted i.e -2 severity?  It's been a couple of decades since I last ran *Rolemaster* and at that time I was playing *Rolemaster Standard System*.

Answer (score 2):

In the Core rules Page 73 it says on the critical EP chart. Critical delivered. So in that light a E critical dropped to a C critical due to a -2 adjustment. XP calculation would be for a C critical.

Comment: Welcome! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).